# Prevent default keyCode 38 and 40

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I prevent the page from scrolling when I press the up and down buttons. KeyCodes 38 and 40. I tried

```
$(window).on("click", function(event){
  var keyCode = event.which;
  if(keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 40){
    preventDefault();
  }
});
```

But it doesn't seem to prevent the page scroll in IE

Comment: Don't you get an error saying `preventDefault is not defined` or something similar?

Comment: yea, I was I just could think of why. It was an amatuer miss. sorry to bother you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `event.preventDefault()`, not just `preventDefault()`. And you need to handle the `keydown` event, not `click`. And on the `document` or `window` object, probably; not `foo`.

Comment: lol. I know, i am calling the window prop, just fast tying the psuedo code. My code is much larger. Sorry about that. Also Thanks bunches about calling the event object. I don't know what I was thinking, this is such an amatuer miss. Thanks again.